# How to add a driver to add data source in Drools Business Central

Tags: datasource, drools

I am using Drools Business Central first time and I am trying to add a data source in Drools but for this I need to add a driver. Can anyone please let me know how can I add a driver in drools, It is asking for Driver class name and I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 0):

For postgres class name is

```
org.postgresql.Driver
```